# Installing python from source in a remote machine with SSL support without sudo access

Tags: python, ssl, pip, openssl, centos

I'm trying to install Python 3.11 on a remote machine running CentOS Linux 7, building from the source. However, after installation, the `pip` is not able to install any modules as it exits with the following error

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, 
however, the SSL module in Python is not available.
```

How can I re-install python with SSL support?

I tried

```
./configure --with-ssl
```

However, I got the error:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-ssl
```

The OpenSSL version installed on the machine is (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021).

Update:
`./configure --help | grep -Fi ssl`
returns:

```
--with-openssl=DIR    root of the OpenSSL directory


--with-openssl-rpath=[DIR|auto|no]
                          Set runtime library directory (rpath) for OpenSSL
                          libraries, no (default): dont set rpath, auto:
                          auto-detect rpath from --with-openssl and
                          pkg-config, DIR: set an explicit rpath
                          
  --with-ssl-default-suites=[python|openssl|STRING]
                          override default cipher suites string, python: use
                          Pythons preferred selection (default), openssl:
                          leave OpenSSLs defaults untouched, STRING: use a
                          custom string, python and STRING also set TLS 1.2 as
                          minimum TLS version
```

Comment: `./configure --help | grep -Fi ssl`

Comment: HI, this returned the following 
``` --with-openssl=DIR      root of the OpenSSL directory
  --with-openssl-rpath=[DIR|auto|no]
                          Set runtime library directory (rpath) for OpenSSL
                          auto-detect rpath from --with-openssl and
  --with-ssl-default-suites=[python|openssl|STRING]
                          Python's preferred selection (default), openssl:
                          leave OpenSSL's defaults untouched, STRING: use a
```
I think we can use the third option, however, I do not understand what to use as the argument.

Comment: Most probably you need `./configure --with-openssl=/usr` but you have to make sure both the headers and the library are installed.

Comment: @phd I suspect not.  I suspect Python 3.x uses OpenSSL 1.1.1 (or maybe even later...).  RHEL/Centos 7 does have the `openssl11` series of packages to install that. but they're not installed in `/usr` in the same locations the OpenSSL 1.0.2 install would be.  "Build from source on a system I don't control and can't install packages on" is more than a little flawed as a deployment strategy.

Comment: Where is OpenSSL 1.1.1 installed?

Comment: @phd `pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl11`  Probably requires something like `openssl11-dev` to be installed.

Comment: Yes, that headers and link libraries. if they're absent I don't see other way but compile and install OpenSSL from sources locally (to directories where you have access like `/usr/local` or `~` (`$HOME`)).

Comment: @phd So now you'd become an OpenSSL install maintainer, too, and have to watch for OpenSSL CVEs and rebuild everything on every system every time a critical CVE is patched in OpenSSL itself.  Again, compiling software from source is more than a little flawed as a deployment strategy.

Comment: @phd How can we find the location in which OpenSSL is installed?

Comment: If you have a kind of `locate` program (`locate`, `mlocate`, `slocate`): `locate -b libssl\*`,  `locate -b ssl\*`. If you don't have `locate` — use `find`.